# What is the command to get up addresses of all the interfaces of my system

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ip-address

Is there any command to read all the configured IP addresses on the system ? In Windows?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Probably `ipconfig /all` though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"').IPAddress